# how to use 'sich lohnen' in a sentence

Tags: word-order, reflexive

How would I order the words in this approximate phrase, and does 'sich lohnen' here give me the right meaning of 'not always worthwhile'?

> Obwohl ich glaube, dass Ehen dauern koennen, lohnen sie sich nicht gern immer.

Comment: Meinst Du vielleicht "Obwohl ich glaube, dass Ehen dauern können, lohnen sie sich nicht immer" oder "lohnen sie sich oft nicht"? Vielleicht besser "Obwohl Ehen dauerhaft sein können ...". Das 'gern' ist jedenfalls ein Fremdkörper im Satz.

Answer (score 3):

> Obwohl ich glaube, dass Ehen dauern koennen, lohnen sie sich nicht <s>gern</s> immer.

That *gern* does not fit a phrase with *lohnen*. Something may *sich wenig/kaum lohnen* or *sich sehr lohnen* or simply *sich lohnen*.

If you wanted to emphasize on the **misfit** between the duration and the worth, use **doch nicht** instead of *nicht*.

> Obwohl ich glaube, dass Ehen dauern koennen, lohnen sie sich **doch nicht** immer.

That's acceptable.

---

After some thought, an author had put it probably as

> Ich glaube an die Ehe als Unternehmung. Und am Ende steht häufig die Insolvenz.

This plays on *die Unternehmung* being both *the excursion* and *the corporation*. A similar joke in English had played on the meaning of *the company*.

No *lohnen* in this example though. But that's okay as German speakers love nouns better than verbs.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the context, *»etwas lohnt sich«* has one of these meanings:

- something is worth it
- something is worthwhile
- something is profitable
- something is worth the trouble

I am confused about the negation that you built into your sentence (»... **nicht** gerne immer«). This makes no sense.

My suggestion is:

> Obwohl ich glaube, dass Ehen *lange* dauern können, lohnen sie sich.

- obwohl = although
- ich glaube = I believe, I think
- dass = that (begin of a relative clause)
- Ehen können lange dauern = marriages can last long
- sie lohnen sich = they are worth the trouble

> Although I believe, that marriages can last *long,* they are worth the trouble.

The three adverbs you added, mean:

- nicht = not
- gern = gladly (etwas gern tun = to like doing something)
- immer = always

So, if you add the adverbs you wanted to use, you get:

> Although I believe, that marriages can last long, they are **not gladly always** worth the trouble.

---

If you omit the word *»lange«* (long) you get a correct sentence, but you reader/listener will have the feeling, that something is missing:

> Obwohl ich glaube, dass Ehen dauern können, lohnen sie sich.
>   Although I believe, that marriages can last, they are worth the trouble.

This is a valid solution, but it is not optimal.

Comment: "Although I believe, that marriages can last long, they are worth the trouble." I believe the intended meaning is rather: "Although I believe, that marriages can last long, they are **not** worth the trouble."

Comment: Das "nicht" in "lohnen sie sich nicht gern immer" ("lohnen sie sich oft nicht"?) hast Du unterwegs verloren und kommst so zu einem ziemlich unsinnigen Schluss: Wenn sie sich lohnen, wieso dann "obwohl"? Da würde doch das gegenteilige "weil" besser passen. Vielleicht erst die Frage klären, bevor man antwortet?

Comment: Yes, what I meant is 'although marriages can last/go the distance, they are not always worth the while' - I put in the 'gern' as I thought it could also be used to mean 'well', as an adverb like 'bien' in French? I gather from your responses, that this is the best translation of my sentence: 'Obwohl ich glaube, dass Ehen dauerhaft sein können, lohnen sie sich nicht immer' = although I believe that marriages can be enduring, they are not always worth the while. What do you guys think?

Comment: @userunknown: Was für einen Sinn hätte denn der Satz *»Obwohl ich glaube, dass Ehen lange dauern können, lohnen sie sich nicht.«*? Da streicht man ja zuerst eine negative Eigenschaft der Ehen hervor (dauert lange) und sagt dann, dass sie trotzdem schlecht sind. Das passt nicht. *»Obwohl ich Angst habe in diesem Viertel überfallen zu werden gehe ich dort *nicht* hin.«* Das ist unsinnig. Der Satz wird erst sinnvoll, wenn man die Verneinung weglässt: *»Obwohl ich Angst habe in diesem Viertel überfallen zu werden gehe ich (immer wieder Mal) dort hin.«*

Comment: Ich denke, wer freiwillig eine Ehe eingeht, verspricht sich von dieser eine lange Dauer. Ehen, die früher auseinandergehen haben sich nicht schneller bezahlt gemacht, sondern sind gescheitert. Lang dauernde Ehen sind i.d.R. die glücklicheren, wiewohl auch äußere Zwänge, Konventionen der Auflösung gescheiterter Ehen entgegenstehen können.